# Перемещение файлов bash-скриптом. Пропадают некоторые файлы

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Возникла задача перемещения файлов, которые появляются в одной папке, в другую папку, смонтированную по NFS. Система Debian. Наваял простой `script-1.sh`, который делает это и поставил на выполнение по крону с периодом раз в минуту. Обнаружилось, что не все файлы перемещаются, некоторые пропадают, т.е. их в src-каталоге уже нет, но в dst-каталоге они не появляются.

Поискал в сети по этой задаче другой скрипт, который отрабатывал бы перемещение по завершению записи в файл. Нашел некий `script-2.sh`, поставил его на выполнение по условию `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`, используя incrontab. Все равно при перемещений файлы некоторые теряются.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой уже. Подскажите, как устранить эту "пропажу" перемещаемых файлов.

script-1.sh:

```
cd /home/user/export/bin
mv * /mnt/receipt/bin
```

script-2.sh:

```
src_dir=$1
dst_dir=$2
subfolder=""

sleep 2 # to set permissions if transferred by putty

for filename in $src_dir/*;
do
    echo "  " $filename
    if [[ -f $filename ]]; then # regular file only
    {
            logger "$0 is going to move $filename -->"
            echo   "$0 is going to move $filename -->"

            case "${filename,,*}" in
                    # this syntax emits the value in lowercase: ${var,,*}  (bash version 4)
                    *.txt) subfolder="bin" ;;
                    *) echo "Unknown file extension, don't know where to put $filename";;
            esac

            if [ -z "$subfolder" ]; then
                    echo "subfolder is unknown $subfolder"
            else
                    chmod 644 "$filename"
                    #chown debian-transmission.samba-read "$filename"

                    mv "$filename" "$dst_dir/$subfolder"
            fi
            logger "$0 finished <--"
    }
    else
    {
            echo "skipping $filename"
    }
    fi
done;
```

### crontab -l

```
*/1     *       *       *       *       /home/user/scripts/export_bin.sh
```

### incrontab table

```
/home/user/export/bin IN_CLOSE_WRITE /home/user/scripts/export_bin.sh $@ /mnt/receipt/bin
```

Comment: Нет, задача другая: переместить файлы из каталога debian в каталог windows, для их обработки некой софтиной. Проблема в том, что эта софтина не умеет авторизоваться в samba-каталог на debian, поэтому приходится перекидывать файлы.

Comment: а откуда файлы берутся? как часто они появляются в этом каталоге? какой примерно размер имеют?

Comment: файлы это документы работы терминала платежной системы cyberft, как часто трудно сказать, закономерности нет, прилетел платежный документ от партнера cyberft, появился файл, размеры небольшие, до килобайта.

Comment: каталог из windows, с которой работает софтина, обрабатывающая файлы, и так уже примонтирован по nfs к debian, в нее и перекидываются документы с терминала.
ЗЫ. Если вы о том чтобы документы с терминала cyberft напрямую кидать в примонтированный каталог из винды, то на это разработчики не идут.

Comment: Я имею в виду обратное: примонтировать к винде каталог из debian. Так можно?

Comment: хм... не думал об этом, спасибо за идею, попробую связаться с виндовс-админами.

Comment: Как можно это дебажить: вместо `mv *` получить список всех файлов и по одному перемещать, и каждый раз `echo $file; stat $file`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у программы *mv* есть опция `-v`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin хм, стоило ожидать чего-то такого )

Comment: по поводу примонтировать каталог с debian на винду: уже расшарен и смонтирован, только проблема в том, что софтина (самописанная), обрабатывающая документы с терминала, не умеет авторизоваться на самбе, собственно поэтому и задача, перекидывать файлы на ресурс винды.

Comment: я подумал, что потерянные файлы, это те документы с терминала, которые еще не успели закрыться, и попали на момент сработки скрипта по крону. чтобы исключить это, перевел крон на incron, и сделал сработку скрипта по событию: закрытие файла IN_CLOSE_WRITE, но не сработало, файлы теряются некоторые все равно.

Comment: А если с помощью rsync?

Answer (score 3):

насколько я понял, изменить поведение программы, которая создаёт файлы в исходном каталоге, и указать ей, чтобы она сохраняла файлы не в `/home/user/export/bin`, а в `/mnt/receipt/bin`, невозможно.

тогда можно заменить каталог `/home/user/export/bin` на символическую ссылку на каталог `/mnt/receipt/bin`:

```
$ rmdir /home/user/export/bin && ln -s /mnt/receipt/bin /home/user/export/bin
```

и больше не потребуется перемещать файлы: они сразу будут сохраняться туда, куда требуется.

Comment: понятно, попробую.

Comment: Разобрались. Проблема была не в скрипте перемещения файлов, а в софтине, которая обрабатывала принятые документы на win-ресурсе. Она, оказывается, удаляла файлы, которые обработала.